# How to subclass SwiftUI classes in kotlin-native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Based on the documentation: [Subclassing Swift/Objective-C classes and protocols from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#subclassing-swift-objective-c-classes-and-protocols-from-kotlin)﻿ I am trying to subclass a SwiftUI class in Kotlin native. I found some examples for [UiKit](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/samples/uikit/src/iosMain/kotlin/ViewController.kt) but no examples for SiwftUI.

This is what I tried so far:

```
import platform.SwiftUI.*

actual class TestClass: ObservableObject() {

}
```

But the import for SwiftUI fails with: `Unresolved reference: SwiftUI`

(A import for `platform.UIKit.*` is working)

My question: Is it even possible to import SwiftUi classes? if yes how sould the correct import look like?

Comment: Are you specifically looking to implement the behavior of `ObservableObject` in Kotlin, while making your class adopt the `ObservableObject` protocol when consumed in Swift? If so there are ways to trivially achieve that through the power of extensions in Objective-C/Swift.

Comment: @NicklasJensen yes that is exactly what I want to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Kotlin/Native` does not offer interop with pure **Swift**. Currently it works indirectly with a `K\N` - `Obj-C` - `Swift` interop. Direct interoperability with `Swift` is on the roadmap, but it's currently paused AFAIK

From the documentation:

> Kotlin/Native provides bidirectional interoperability with
> Objective-C" ... "A Swift library can be used in Kotlin code if its
> API is exported to Objective-C with @objc. Pure Swift modules are not
> yet supported.

Since `SwiftUI` is pure Swift, you can't really import it to Kotlin unfortunately (hopefully yet).